# Bing Maps REST returning bad directions when passing waypoints

Tags: android, bing-maps, directions

I'm working on an Android app that utilizes BING maps and their directions REST service.  I allow the user to input origin, destination, and avoid types (i.e. avoid highways, tolls, etc...) to obtain directions.  After BING returns the directions I display them on a BING map and then allow the user to save the directions.  I save each waypoint that is involved.  The user later can display their saved directions back on a BING map.  At this point I pass each waypoint to BING to get the directions.  As you can see in the screen shots below, the first directions are created with just an Origin and Destination (and avoid types), and the second one is purely created on passing each waypoint that was saved.

I've confirmed that the waypoints that come back from the initial request are the exact same as the waypoints I'm saving and passing back to BING.

Here are some live queries that I used for the screens below:
[My generated link to BING REST](http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Driving?wp.0=40.797768,-111.947299&wp.1=40.793368,-111.943672&wp.2=40.7934,-111.939231&wp.3=40.725911,-111.939&wp.4=40.725589,-111.911137&wp.5=40.72546,-111.888247&wp.6=40.725439,-111.87122&wp.7=40.6657,-111.864848&wp.8=40.63854,-111.834571&wp.9=40.637478,-111.808838&wp.10=40.619352,-111.789488&wp.11=40.633739,-111.723919&wp.12=40.631808,-111.71923&optmz=time&rpo=Points&tl=3.0E-6&du=Mile)
[Query with each waypoint](http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=40.70858203667544~-111.83644562959671&lvl=11&dir=0&sty=r&rtp=pos.40.797768_-111.947299_40.797768,%20-111.947299___e_~pos.40.793368_-111.943672_40.793368,%20-111.943672___e_~pos.40.7934_-111.939231_40.7934,%20-111.939231___e_~pos.40.725911_-111.939_40.725911,%20-111.939___e_~pos.40.725589_-111.911137_40.725589,%20-111.911137___e_~pos.40.72546_-111.888247_40.72546,%20-111.888247___e_~pos.40.725439_-111.87122_40.725439,%20-111.87122___e_~pos.40.6657_-111.864848_40.6657,%20-111.864848___e_~pos.40.63854_-111.834571_40.63854,%20-111.834571___e_~pos.40.637478_-111.808838_40.637478,%20-111.808838___e_~pos.40.619352_-111.789488_40.619352,%20-111.789488___e_~pos.40.633739_-111.723919_40.633739,%20-111.723919___e_~pos.40.631808_-111.71923_40.631808,%20-111.71923___e_&mode=D&rtop=0~0~0~&form=LMLTCC)

Any ideas as to what is going on or what I can do to fix this? It's like BING wants to further optimize the route, but ends up making it worse.  In the second picture you can see it has you get off the freeway, then back on, then get off again and then back track to where you just got off.

Good Route with initial input with Origin and Destination:
[image: Initial map with origin and destination entered. This is good]

Bad Route being obtained with saved waypoints:
[image: waypoint route]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a problem with the bing library. Have you tried filling a bug report with them?

Comment: I have, but haven't heard back.